# SQL Query to Get data in Pivot Table model

Tags: sql, linq, pivot-table

I am looking for a SQL query to get SQL data in a Pivot Table model.

SQL Table Data

| Code | CustomerName | Type | Items | EntryDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C0001 | Thomas | BREAKFAST | Milk | 2018-04-25 14:03:12.340 |
| C0001 | Thomas | BREAKFAST | Bread | 2018-04-20 12:03:12.340 |
| C0001 | Thomas | BREAKFAST | Egg | 2018-04-25 12:03:12.340 |
| C0001 | Thomas | LUNCH | Rice | 2018-04-10 11:03:12.340 |
| C0001 | Thomas | LUNCH | Fish Curry | 2018-04-12 11:03:12.340 |
| C0001 | Thomas | LUNCH | Lessy | 2018-04-15 11:03:12.340 |
| C0001 | Thomas | DINNER | Bread | 2018-04-25 14:03:12.340 |
| C0001 | Thomas | DINNER | Jam | 2018-04-25 14:03:12.340 |

By using the below SQl Query

```
WITH data_CTE( id, Type, Items,RID ,Code, CustomerName)
AS

(

SELECT id, Type, Items,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY (Type)ORDER BY  id) AS RID ,Code, CustomerName
  FROM Table1 

)

SELECT Code, CustomerName, [BREAKFAST], [LUNCH], [DINNER]

FROM

(SELECT  Type, Items,RID ,Code, CustomerName

FROM data_CTE)C

PIVOT

(

max(Items)

FOR Type IN ([BREAKFAST], [LUNCH], [DINNER])

) AS PivotTable;
```

I get the output as:

| Code | CustomerName | BREAKFAST | LUNCH | DINNER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C0001 | Thomas | Milk | null | Bread |
| C0001 | Thomas | null | null | Jam |
| C0001 | Thomas | Bread | null | null |
| C0001 | Thomas | Egg | null | null |
| C0001 | Thomas | null | Fish Curry | null |
| C0001 | Thomas | null | Rice | null |

The above output is gets null if the entrydate is not same. I need the output as below even if there are many other field also.

| Code | CustomerName | BREAKFAST | LUNCH | DINNER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C0001 | Thomas | Milk | Rice | Bread |
| C0001 | Thomas | Bread | Lessy | Jam |
| C0001 | Thomas | Egg | Fish Curry |  |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like below.

```
WITH data_CTE( id, Type, Items,RID ,Code, CustomerName)
AS

(

SELECT id, Type, Items,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY (Type)ORDER BY  id) AS RID ,Code, CustomerName
  FROM Table1 

)

SELECT Code, CustomerName, [BREAKFAST], [LUNCH], [DINNER]

FROM

(SELECT  Type, Items,RID ,Code, CustomerName

FROM data_CTE)C

PIVOT

(

max(Items)

FOR Type IN ([BREAKFAST], [LUNCH], [DINNER])

) AS PivotTable;
```

Here is the [Sample Code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fe2bc/1)

Comment: How to add Where condition like where Customercode ='C0001'. If I use FoodMaster table for Bread, Milk, etc how can I use with Join statement. How can I add more fields like customer address, room number, etc

Comment: SELECT id, Type, Items,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY (Type)ORDER BY  id) AS RID ,Code, CustomerName
  FROM YOurTableName WHERE  Customercode ='C0001'

Comment: Thank you So much Prabhath Amaradasa, I marked it as Answer and you helped me lot.

Comment: How can I add "Group By" clause in above query ?

Comment: What data you want to get by applying a GROUP BY in above query?

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are 3 types in the table so i planned to give them some ranks according to their types and on that i used pivot to get the expected result :

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER  (PARTITION BY TYPE ORDER BY ITEMS DESC ) 
    ID,CODE,CUSTOMERNAME,ITEMS,TYPE FROM YOUR_TABLE
) PIVOT (
    MAX(ITEMS)
    FOR TYPE IN ('BREAKFAST', 'LUNCH','DINNER')
) ORDER BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER  (PARTITION BY TYPE ORDER BY ITEMS DESC ) 
ID,CODE,CUSTOMERNAME,ITEMS,TYPE FROM YOUR_TABLE
)

PIVOT
(
 MAX(ITEMS)
 FOR TYPE IN ('BREAKFAST', 'LUNCH','DINNER')
) 
ORDER BY ID
```